# Change div text if Select contains option with specific text

Tags: jquery

I have a CMS that multiple people administer. We enable/disable some of our shipping methods depending on the time of year. I want to setup our checkout page to display a different message in our pickup info TD if someone enables the "Text Reserv. Pick-up" shipping option, but leave it as the default if not.

I've found plenty of examples to change a div or something else if an option is selected, but I just want to see if an option is in the list and then change the content of a TD based on that. I've tried modified of those examples to see if it will work for my situation, but haven't got it to work.

I already have the code to change the TD, but can't figure out how to check to see if the select contains a certain option first. Here's the code I have to change the text and input button of the TD:

```
// Change description from "To pick up at the bookstore" on Step 2 of checkout to Reserve Your Textbooks
$('td[id$=PickupAtStoreColumn] div.multipleship').each(function() { $(this).html($(this).html().replace("To pick up at the bookstore","Reserve Your Textbooks")); });

// Change "Pick Up At Store" button text on Step 2 of checkout to Reservation Pickup
$('td[id$=PickupAtStoreColumn] input[id$=btnPickupAtStore]').attr('value','Reservation Pick-up');
```

How can I check to see if select[id$=drpShipType] has "Text Reserv. Pick-up" enabled as an option first? Thanks!

Comment: just as an aside, IDs should be unique to the page. So there's no point selecting a particular type of element with a particular ID, just select the ID: `$('#PickupAtStoreColumn')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your select element's options have values specified, you can detect whether the option exists via:

```
$('#drpShipType option[value="Text Reserv. Pick-up"]').length > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `is` method:

```
 $('someSelector').is(':selected')
```

This returns a boolean true / false to tell you if it is selected or not. However, in your situation, you're asking if a specific option is selected or not. The only way I would think would be valid would be grab the specific option selected, and then check a value on it. For example:

```
<option value="4" class="specificGuy">Text Reserv. Pick-up</option>

$('.specificGuy').is(':selected')
```